# sorting array after json retrieval

Tags: c#, json, sorting

I have the following code, which works fine, that parses JSON.

EVENT and SQUAD are JSON arrays.

What code would I need to be able to sort the arrays, for example sorting EVENT on TIME, or SQUAD on RANK?

```
void client_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(gameDetails));
            gameDetails jsResult = (gameDetails)serializer.ReadObject(e.Result);

        ...
        }
        [DataContract]
        public class gameDetails
        {
            [DataMember]
            public string HomeTeamScore { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string AwayTeamScore { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string FixtureDate { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string HomeTeamName { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string AwayTeamName { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "EVENT")]
            public EVENT[] EVENTS;
            [DataMember(Name = "SQUADS")]
            public SQUAD[] SQUADS;

        }
        [DataContract]
        public class EVENT
        {
            [DataMember]
            public string TEAMFLAG { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string TIME { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string PLAYER { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string TYPE { get; set; }
        }

        [DataContract]
        public class SQUAD
        {
            [DataMember]
            public string PLSURN { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string PLID { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string PLAYER { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string TEAM { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string PLFORN { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string SQUADNO { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string RANK { get; set; }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this for sorting EVENTS:

```
jsResult.EVENTS = jsResult.EVENTS.OrderBy(e=>e.TIME).ToArray();
```

Note that TIME is string and you might want to convert it before sorting.

Comment: perfect! I had tried many different things and couldn't get it working, simple when you know how!  I've changed `TIME` and a couple of other variables to `int` to aid with the sorting.